# Duplicating the partition key onto a clustering key

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

Not sure if the question's title sounds crazy but I thought about this and I'd like to check the "validity" of the pro's and con's I imagine.

The ideal C* query in "production" targets only one partition, possibly with additional restrictions on the clustering keys. A data model should be designed with that in mind.

However, for analytics jobs, e.g. using **Spark**, the queries **would** not work like that: "searching" for specific partitions is often needed (and I could not find a way to do that properly with SparkSQL and the dataframe API) and it **should** not work like this: a Spark job should target many partitions to spread over all the co-located Spark/Cassandra nodes.

My data model works in such a way that acquiring my data in real time inserts partitions as a whole. My partitions are "atomic": a large analytics job with Spark will mainly correlate data within one partition (which is good as it allows data locality for the Spark executor) but my main problem is to find on which partitions I want to operate.

So, what about duplicating my partition key and have it as a clustering key as well? This would allow me to build a [SASI index](http://rustyrazorblade.com/2016/02/cassandra-secondary-index-preview-1/) on it and have the "best of both worlds" just at the cost of the additional storage.

Would this be a sound strategy?